# Not able to get directory structure and Maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, groovy

I have checked out a Maven project from Subversion. It has Java with Spring framework and Groovy.

We are using **Groovy Eclipse compiler** plugin. On **Maven install**, code compiles perfectly with Groovy Eclipse compiler and a jar is created in target.

But there is no directory structure which is usually created in Maven. No classpath too.

I tried many things nothing worked. Finally I converted project to faceted form and then src/java was created as it was faceted to Java project. Still no Maven dependencies.

As there was no Maven dependencies, many jars were missing, so I added jars to build path manually. I also added src/groovy to build path and then it was not able to compile Groovy classes, so I configured project as Groovy project and DDSL was generated. Now after so many manual settings, it is not working fine when it has to create object using spring for Maven class.

I tried a project without Spring framework, and it worked fine.

For pom.xml: I have referred: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/tools-groovyeclipse.html.

Comment: Did you attempt to add the Maven nature?

Comment: its already a maven project,  so I think by default Maven nature.

Comment: No, Eclipse won't make it a Maven project unless you tell it to, or if you specifically imported it as a maven project. If you just checked it out from SVN and opened it as a plain project, that's all that Eclipse knows.

Comment: You can tell by looking at the project icon in the package explorer.  If there's a little M at the bottom of the icon, then it knows it's a mavenproject. It will also show the pom.xml in a different icon. If not, then it doesn't know it's a maven project.

Comment: oh yes, I imported it as maven project only.